# Why am I banned from asking questions after posting a valid question?

Tags: support, specific-question

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52133973/settimeout-in-a-for-loop-with-array-as-an-argument-misbehaving), with responses from other users has got me banned. I believe I posted a legitimate question without disrespecting or offending anyone. I figured out the issue in the code after doing some debugging as suggested by other users.

I am still not sure why I got banned. Can I please have a review?

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Comment: Don you have any deleted questions that are closed and/or < 0 scored?

Comment: If anything, the code in that specific question is not exactly what we meant with *Minimal* when you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: A question with an answer pointing out multiple, distinct issues is not a good thing...

Comment: Deleted questions, score < 0: ([1](//stackoverflow.com/q/43900985) [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/43864518) [3](//stackoverflow.com/q/43845272))

Comment: Welcome on the SO! The banning script counts 3 things: 1) your question is downvoted 2) your question is closed 3) your question is deleted. Having a downvoted, closed and deleted question means 3 minus, but a downvoted, open and not deleted one is a minus, too.

Comment: The shortest question ban is only 2 weeks, the exact details are kept secret by the company, but you may have luck! If you have own-deleted questions, undelete them (1 minus away), and try to fix them! The details of the unban are hidden, too, but maybe even one or two upvotes are enough!

Comment: We all know that (or at least if you don't, read the duplicate target first) question ban is triggered by bad question. It would be better if you post your worst questions here and ask how to improve it instead.

Answer (score 9):

It is likely (though not certain) that you've just been tipped over the edge into the ban. A few upvotes will get you out of it.

If I have one bit of advice for the future it's to learn how to create a smaller, more abstract, version of your code - a minimal, complete and verifiable example (MVCE). By gradually removing code and turning your issue into a much smaller one you can often see what the problem is straight away. If you can't that's also fine, but you then have a general problem that someone else has likely already solved or will find very easy to solve.